# What made these burrows and holes in my lawn (Picture inside)

Tags: hole, lawn

I just moved to upstate NY area. I don't have too much experience with lawn but I know my lawn is terrible compared to my neighbors'.

I took this picture today. There are clearly some activities under my lawn. I think it is killing my lawn because the upper left area in the photo is grass-less before I moved in. What animals are those? How can I get rid of them?
[image: Picture 1]

These holes below may not related to the first one because there wasn't any burrow. Just quarter size holes. What animal made these?
[image]
[image]

Comment: At least whatever is making those holes is leaving quarters behind. ;-)

Comment: Clever of them to find a lost coin to use as a lid, though...

Comment: Thanks for including the size reference in the photo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely moles are the culprits in the first photo. As has already been mentioned, moles forage for insects and larvae that dwell in the lawns top soil. They don't harm the grass when they dig. The soil that is moved is pushed behind them and remain under the lawn so the grass will continue growing. For a non-toxic repellent I've read of castor oil mix with water in a spray tank and applied to the ground keeps them at bay.

The second and third photo's showing the tunnel opening is probably a mole and not a gopher. The pocket gopher will collect the soil that it excavates when tunneling in a large cheek pouch and disperse it out side so it fan shaped. Gophers will destroy lawns, but I believe they haven't colonized in your neck of the woods.

Comment: They DO harm the grass! They cause molehills, which cover large (in comparison to their own size) areas with soil, under which the grass dies. -1.

Answer (score 2):

There are both species in your area.  In the wintertime, the gophers go deep below the frost line.  Pocket gopher pups do leave open holes like this without a mound of dirt.  Typically this indicates they are 2 weeks old and are learning how to tunnel.  Within 2 weeks more, if a huge mound appears,then consider a female pup pregnant.

Moles are not here in Arizona but I have trapped them before in other states as I’m a Wildlife Specialist.  They do tunnel just underneath the surface consuming grubs and worms as it was mentioned before.  They do have eyes, just thought I’d mention it as many think they don’t.  They’re just tiny and buried in all that fur.  Moles are not as destructive to homes and pools as gophers, bother leave yards looking ugly, moles leave endless connect the dots patterns and gophers leave open holes, mounds and plant destruction.

You may have both but I’m leaning more towards moles.  The traps for moles are different and are aboveground.  Trapping is the only “true method” for both.

If you need additional help, let me know.

Comment: That makes it 4 such posts, please vote accordingly

Comment: @RohitGupta - your dv and comments are without a good explanation. Please be way more explicit.

Comment: @Tim I have come across at least 4, maybe 5 posts by Gopher Expert, answering virtually the same blurb (slightly rephrased) on old posts and soliciting off-line work.  I think one might have had a link.  So, to me, it's a bit spammy.  It probably isn't going to help the OPs.

Comment: If so, mark as suspected spam. Simple.

Comment: As noted in one of the others, posting a compete and useful answer and then saying "by the way, here's my card" is exactly the *right* way to promote a business on SE.

Comment: @RohitGupta spammy?  I’ve sent an email to the admins regarding your claims.  I was asked to come here and clarify the facts on the species, as this is what I do and have been for over 55 years.  There is so much bad information here, including violations of federal labels of deadly products, but because you have an issue with my responding to what I specialize in, I’m in the wrong.  You claim one thing, now keshlam says offer my card?  How about you guys make up your minds?  “Slightly rephrased?”  I’m the leading expert and have the only certification course on the planet means I know facts.

Comment: @Tim how is my answering posts spam?  People come here looking for answers; put in the topic of their search and hit enter.  Old questions come up, correct?  Why can’t I respond to those, the original poster may still have issues, what if others have the same?  So I’m being singled out and rohitgupta is now stalking all of my posts?  This is more than my knowledge on the subject, this is personal on his part.  I’ll keep recording all of my screens, comments and all posts regarding my comments.

Comment: @GopherExpert - I have absolutely no axe to grind. It seems you know what you talk about, at least gopher-wise. It's just Rohit who seems to have a bee in his bonnet. All I did was point him in the direction if he was unhappy with your answers. Keep 'em coming! I gave you +1 for one answer!

Comment: Thanks Tim and you’re right, he does.  He’s gone after every single post I’ve made.  I do know pocket gophers, he’s in NZ where there are none, his complaints on my posts have garnered complaints for violations of code of conduct.  I came here at someone else’s request to help give free advice and help.  That’s what’s so messed up, I’m here on my own time, not sleeping so I can help others and he's deliberately hurting my reputation, keeping me from answering questions, when I could be sleeping.   I do appreciate your responding, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Those look like mole runs under the sod. That is how they move around. They eat grubs and worms just under the root layer of the grass. Eliminate their food source and they will leave.

You can treat the lawn with grub killer or nematodes that kill the grubs. I have had these for years. They come and go but when I treat the lawn they seem to leave for a season.

Good luck!